# PG timezone offsets inverted?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I can't understand this behavior in Postgres 15:

```
set timezone = 'UTC-4';
select now(), cast(now() as timestamp without time zone)
```

I get: `2023-10-26 13:47:45.202867 +04:00` and `2023-10-26 13:47:45.202867`. But why does it say `+04:00` if I just set my timezone offset to `-04:00`? Bug?

Everything's fine when setting the actual timezone (like `Asia/Yerevan`, `Europe/Helsinki`). The problem seems to be only with the offsets.